# How to convert 5 stars rating to pixels in python?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two different rates that the user can make for his teacher , i want to convert the total of each rate in pixels so i can have the progress bar effect, for example:

```
maximum_pixels = 100 #maximum width
services = 4.5 #width: 95px
professionalism = 5.0 #width: 100px
total_percentage = maximum_pixels * services / maximum_pixels
```

How can i implement that in my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
maxAllowed = 100
minAllowed = 0
unscaledNum = 3
_min = 0
_max = 5
((maxAllowed - minAllowed) * (unscaledNum - _min) / (_max - _min) + minAllowed)
```

Result:

```
60.0
```

Comment: So i need also to define the maximum number of rates , thanks dude it worked perfectly :) .

Comment: Your answer is accepted but i can't vote for it right now becuase my reputation is low ;)

Comment: You're welcome, you can mark it as correct if you want :)